# How to move braces with a mobject in manimgl?

Tags: manim

I want to create a scene which `x_n` move forth and back, and the left of brace movement with `x_n`, and there is dynamical number under the brace, just like the picture as. How can I do that?
[image: rendering figure]
I want to make a demonstration of limit about number series limitation, but I don't know how to make it.

Comment: In manim community I would use a combination of `Tex`, `Brace`, `Arrow`, `updateFromFunc`, `Transform` and `DecimalNumber`. Maybe also the `add_updater()` function is needed. I don't know if all these classes are also available in manimgl. 

I don't think you will find someone here who will just code you this scene. Start learning manim and try to do it yourself. If you are stuck at a specific point, you can ask this question here.